# Switch to text mode instead of fundamental mode for org examples

Tags: org-mode

```
#+begin_example
#+end
```

`C-c C-'` on example starts a buffer in fundamental mode.  Could it be replaced with text mode?

Comment: How about?:  `#+BEGIN_SRC text` and `#+END_SRC`

Comment: begin_example would be more preferrable.

Comment: You can set the default value of `major-mode` to `text-mode` and forego `fundamentail-mode` completely: `(setq-default major-mode 'text-mode)`; but that may be a blunt instrument.

Comment: It looks like the logic for setting the mode is in `org-edit-src-code`, which tests whether it's a src block or not. It passes the mode to the initialize parameter of `org-src--edit-element`. You might be able to advice one of these functions to change the initialize parameter to text-mode but I haven't figured out how.

Comment: The example in my comment above also included the word `text` which is a parameter (on the first line) being passed to tell Emacs to use `text-mode` when entering an org source edit buffer.  Go ahead and give it a try.  Once you very that the example in my comment above works as advertised, then you can experiment with changing the names of the example portion and so forth.

Comment: @amitp: for example blocks, the `initialize` parameter is nil. It's only for source blocks that it is the language-mode. One possibility is to modify the code to recognize a language mode for example blocks too. But that requires code changes, so the quickest workaround is to turn the example blocks to source blocks as @lawlist suggests. I don't see an easy way to advise any of the functions involved to do what's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for setting the mode is in `org-edit-src-code`. This tests whether it's a src block or not. If it's an example block, it passes `nil` to the initialize parameter of `org-src--edit-element`.

We can intercept this call using the "advice" feature in `:filter-args` mode. This will give us a list of arguments to `org-src--edit-element`. We can change the arguments before `org-src--edit-element` sees them. Specifically, we can change `nil` to `text-mode`:

```el
(defun my/use-text-mode-org-comments (args)
  "Use text-mode for editing comments"
  ;; argument 2 is the mode to use for editing; 
  ;; it is nil when editing example blocks
(defun my/use-text-mode-org-comments (args)
  "Use text-mode for editing comments"
  (unless (nth 2 args)
    (setf (nth 2 args) 'text-mode))
  args)

(advice-add 'org-src--edit-element 
            :filter-args #'my/use-text-mode-org-comments)
```

This code will change example blocks to be edited in text mode instead of fundamental mode.

Comment: `nth` returns a place, so you could replace the `append` with `(unless (nth 2 args) (setf (nth 2 args) 'text-mode))`

Comment: Thank you rpluim! I've updated the answer with that.